# how to check the latest version of a clojure library on clojars?

Tags: clojure

I am using pomegranate's add-dependencies function:

```
(add-dependencies :coordinates '[[incanter "1.2.3"]]
                  :repositories {"clojars" "http://clojars.org/repo"})
```

However, I don't usually know what the latest version of incanter (or any other project). Is there a way to check for that programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach (which might work but I haven't tested it yet) would be to use `"RELEASE"` as the artifact version. That's,  for example, how lein-try does it.

```
(add-dependencies '[[incanter "RELEASE"]] ...)
```

Comment: I think the ancient-clj is sufficient. I want to write a function on top of pomegranate and ancient-clj so it dumbs down dynamically installing files: (pull "hiccup")

Comment: Are you sure? This here is probably the easiest solution, requiring no additional dependencies. ancient-clj is more of a way to inspect/compare versions of an artifact - it is overkill to use it for collecting just the latest one. Have you tried `(add-dependencies '[[incanter "RELEASE"]] ...)`?

Comment: Oh... That's really neat. I'll give that a go!

Comment: oh wow. (add-dependencies :coordinates '[[hiccup "RELEASE"]] :repositories {"clojars" "http://clojars.org/repo"}) works a treat

Answer (score 7):

```
$ lein ancient
[com.taoensso/timbre "2.6.2"] is available but we use "2.1.2"
[potemkin "0.3.3"] is available but we use "0.3.0"
[pandect "0.3.0"] is available but we use "0.2.3"
```

[clojars](https://clojars.org/lein-ancient)

Answer (score 1):

The library behind lein-ancient is [ancient-clj](https://github.com/xsc/ancient-clj). It might be what you want.

Another solution would be to slurp the contents of the Clojars artifact HTML page and search for the string indicating the latest release version. This should be around 5 lines, I guess, without the need for an extra dependency.

Comment: Is that what you did for ancient-clj?

Comment: No, ancient-clj uses the artifact metadata (stored as XML e.g. [here](https://clojars.org/repo/ancient-clj/ancient-clj/maven-metadata.xml)) to determine the available versions.

Comment: How would snapshots be excluded?

Comment: I should really update/restructure the documentation. Every function takes an optional map as the first parameter wherein you can specify `:snapshot? false` to exclude SNAPSHOTs and `:qualified? false` to exclude alpha/beta/... versions.